# Jersey 2 resource needs to cleanup

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have a singleton resource that creates objects in its constructor, and when the application shuts down, and the server terminates, I need to release these objects. How is this done in Jersey 2?

```
@Path("/")
@Singleton
public class MyResource {
    private Map<String, MyObject> cache;

    public MyResource() {
        cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        // at some point I need to remove all entries
        // from the map and close all MyObject objects there
        //
        // the reason is because MyObject might have files open
        // and I need to close the files
        //
        // where can I do that?
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific that "at some point".  At /which/ point?   The whole point of container-managed lifecycles is that those points are defined and become configuration items.   Calling a "release/clear these now" method manually totally abuses the whole idea.

Comment: Thanks. I will edit the question.

Comment: (Also, as a general you probably don't want container-managed lifecycles to be opening/closing files.  That's not what CDI is for.)

Comment: I am new to Java development, would you please give more information about what you are talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jersey supports the `@PreDestroy` lifecycle hook. So just annotate a method in the class with `@PreDestroy`, and Jersey will call it before the resource is disposed

```
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

@Path("/")
@Singleton
public class MyResource {
    private Map<String, MyObject> cache;

    public MyResource() {
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        // do cleanup
    }
}
```